# Infinitesimal generator of $3$-dimensional Stochastic differential equation

Tags: markov-process, stochastic-analysis

I'm in the process of learning the poste [Lecture1-The Paul Levy stochstic area formula](https://fabricebaudoin.wordpress.com/2016/06/30/lecture-1-the-paul-levys-stochastic-area-formula/) but I have some question of this topic.
Consider the case of the Levy area
$$
S_t=\int_0^t B^1_s dB^2_s-B^2_s dB^1_s,
$$
where $B_t=(B^1_t,B^2_t)$, $t \ge 0$, is a two dimensional Brownian motion started at $0$.
 The $3$-dimensional process $X_t=(B^1_t,B^2_t,S_t)$, is solution of a stochastic differential equation
\begin{align*}
dX^1_t &  =dB^1_t\\
dX^2_t &  =dB^2_t\\
dX^3_t &  =-X^2_t dB^1_t+X^1_t dB^2_t
\end{align*}

I do not understand this claim:

### As a consequence $X_t$ is a Markov process with generator $$ L=\frac{1}{2} (X^2+Y^2) $$ where $X,Y$ are the following vector fields \begin{align*} X&=\frac{\partial}{\partial x}-y \frac{\partial}{\partial z}\\ Y&=\frac{\partial}{\partial y}+x \frac{\partial}{\partial z}. \end{align*}

The above system of stochastic differential equations can be written as:
\begin{equation}
d X_t=
        \begin{pmatrix}
         1 & 0 \\
          0 & 1 \\
          -X^2_t &X^2_t \\
        \end{pmatrix}
                     \begin{pmatrix}
                       dB^1_t \\
                       dB^2_t
                     \end{pmatrix}
\end{equation}
I have confusion to apply the It\^o lemma in the multidimensional case because the
 the matrix 
 \begin{equation*}
  \begin{pmatrix}
         1 & 0 \\
          0 & 1 \\
          -X^2_t &X^2_t \\
        \end{pmatrix}
 \end{equation*}
is not square.

Thank you for your compehension.